# @OneToOne with shared key between three tables

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping, one-to-one

I have three entities who share the same primary key. There is a bidirectional one-to-one relationship between the **Account** and **Provider** entity, where the previously named entities *share their primary key*, but at the same time the **Provider** entity shares the primary key with the **GlobalRating** entity, where there is a unidirectional relationship between them. I must say that I am using hibernate with MySQL as a database:

**Account Entity:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="account")
@Getter
@Setter
@JsonIdentityInfo(
          generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, 
          property = "email")
public class Account implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO, generator="native")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "native", strategy = "native")
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "account", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Provider provider;
}
```

**Provider Entity:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="provider")
@Getter
@Setter
@JsonIdentityInfo(
          generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, 
          property = "providerId")
public class Provider implements Serializable, Comparable<Provider>{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="pk_account$provider")
    @GeneratedValue(generator="native")
    @GenericGenerator(name="native", strategy="foreign",parameters=@Parameter(name="property", value="account"))
    private int providerId;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private Account account;

    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, optional = false)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private GlobalRating globalRating;
}
```

**GlobalRating Entity:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="global_rating")
@Getter
@Setter
public class GlobalRating implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="pk_provider$global_rating")
    @GeneratedValue(generator="native")
    @GenericGenerator(name="native", strategy="foreign",parameters=@Parameter(name="property", value="globalRating"))
    private int globalRatingId;
}
```

The problem that I have is when creating an **Account** with a **Provider** and a **GlobalRating**. I am sure that the bidirectional mapping between **Account** and **Provider** works, but the problem lies in the mapping of the entity **Provider** and the entity **GlobalRating**. I have tried it in several ways but it does not work. So, how is this case mapped correctly in hibernate?

I appreciate that you can help me with this.